# What VBA Code to Hide Excel Quick Access Toolbar?

Tags: excel, vba, toolbar

I am interested in code that only manipulates (hides and makes Visible) the Excel Quick Access Toolbar.  the code that I have hides the toolbar hides the entire Ribbon Structure'

My existing Code (Hides Everything):
'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"", False)"

It is easily hidden by the manual method under the options menu, but Excel won't record a macro to follow those manual Steps:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the next pice of code:

```
Sub HideQuickAccessTB()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
End Sub
```

To show it, use the next version:

```
Sub ShowQuickAccessTB()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub
```

Comment: no that does not work.  That is the same code I am using, please see the second paragraph above in my question.

Comment: that takes away the entire ribbon, not just the quick-access toolbar.  The VBA CODE I am looking for should act just like the manual method of removing only the quick access toolbar available through the options menu checkbox